# Cannot disable port 8080 from Jenkins config

Tags: security, ssl, jenkins, port, config

I changed the `JENKINS_PORT="-1"` (was `JENKINS_PORT="8080"` by default) in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Enabled 8443 by setting `JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT="8443"`

Restarted Jenkins using `Systemctl`. Access to Jenkins on 8080 Still working, while 8443 is not.

OS: Centos 7
Java: 8
Jenkins: 2.346.3